# Stack Pop program in c, returning wrong output everytime

Tags: c

I am a beginner in programming. I just made this program in c language for popping elements from Stack. Firstly, I defined function, then scanned a stack and then used a menu for popping elements. But the output is "The stack is empty" everytime. Can you spot the mistake? It will be of great help.

```
/* Program to Pop elements from a given stack*/
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#define MAX_SIZE 20
int stack[MAX_SIZE],top=NULL;
int pop()                             //function define
{
 int x;
 if(top==NULL)
 return(NULL);
 else
 {
 x=stack[top];
 top=top-1;
 return(x);
 }
}
main()                             //program initialization
{
int c,i,x;
clrscr();
printf("Enter the size of stack:");
scanf("%d",&top);
printf("Enter %d elements of stack from top to bottom:",top);
for(i=top;i>0;i--)
scanf("%d",stack[i]);
//Pop element from stack
while(1) 
{
 printf("1.Enter 1 to Pop element from stack\n");
 printf("2.Enter 2 to Print Stack\n");
 printf("3.Enter 3 to Exit\n");
 scanf("%d",&c);
 switch(c)
 {
  case 1:
  {
  x=pop();
  if(x!=NULL)
  printf("\nThe number poped is: %d\n",x);
  else
  printf("\nThe stack is empty!!");
  break;
  }
  case 2:
  {
  if(top==NULL)
  printf("stack is empty!!\n");
  else
   {
  printf("stack is\n");
  for(i=top;i>0;i--)
  printf("%d\n",stack[i]);
   }
  break;
  }
  case 3:
  {
  exit(0);
  break;
  }
  default:
  {
  printf("Wrong input\n");
  }
  printf("\n");
 }
getch();
}
}
```

Comment: Why the c# tag?

Comment: `scanf("%d",stack[i]);` this should be fixed to `scanf("%d",&stack[i]);`

Comment: NULL is the value of a _null-pointer_, you are comparing it to integers - you should use zero (0) here, not NULL.   `x` being zero is not the same as the stack being empty - zero is a valid integer value and may be the value on the stack.

Comment: It would make more sense perhaps to create a `push()` function and initialise your stack by iterating `push()` operations.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf("%d",stack[i]);` - this line which fills in the `stack` should be fixed to `scanf("%d",&stack[i]);`

`scanf` should receive the address(es) of the parameter(s) to be able to modify it (them). Please check the `scanf` [documentation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_scanf.htm) for more details and options.

Also please verify the return value of `scanf` as it is explained here: [how do we test the return values from the scanf() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10084224/how-do-we-test-the-return-values-from-the-scanf-function)