# I'm trying to have the user hit the <ENTER> key to exit my C program

Tags: c, getchar

I'm trying to have the user hit the ENTER key to exit my program.  I am using the

```
(void) getchar();
```

getchar function to wait for the user to press the ENTER key.  This worked for a simple Hello world program that did not request any user input, but in this program with the user inputting a double, the program skips the getchar command.  If I double-click on the "Lab 1B.exe" executable code, after the user inputs the double side A of the triangle, the executable window with the running program disappears (the program skips the getchar command).  How do I get the program to wait for the user to type the ENTER key?

How do I get the program to wait for the user to type any key???

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    double a = 0, b = 0, c = 0;
    //int x = 0;
    double x = 0;

    printf("Lab 1B - Triangles:\n\n");
    printf("Enter the length of your triangle's side A: ");
    scanf_s("%lf", &a);
    printf("The length of the triangle's side A is: ");
    printf("%lf", a);
    printf("\n");


    printf("\nPress the <ENTER> key to exit.\n");
    (void) getchar();
    
    //printf("\nEnter any value to exit: ");
    //scanf_s("%i", &x);
    //scanf_s("%lf", &x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Assuming `scanf_s` is like `scanf`, you might just try adding a space to the end of the format string: `scanf_s("%lf ")`

Comment: @WilliamPursell A poor idea (for `scanf` anyway, IDK about scanf_s) , as that means it will never stop reading until a non-whitespace character is input

Comment: All of the answers posted here are wrong;  please see the question we've linked that has good answers (or at least, a good accepted answer)

Comment: @M.M A better characterization is "it will skip whitespace".  That is usually the desired behavior, and seems to be what the OP wants.

Comment: @WilliamPursell OP wants the code to continue with the next statement once the person types their response and presses Enter (which will not happen with your suggestion)

Answer (score 0):

`scanf()` leaves a trailing `newline` character that is later consumed by your `getchar()` call. If you are always getting the input via the user and not redirection or another FILE stream, you could have another `getchar()` call after your `scanf()` call. You should check the result of `scanf()` more on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10084224/how-do-we-test-the-return-values-from-the-scanf-function).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  double a = 0, b = 0, c = 0;
  double x = 0;

  printf("Lab 1B - Triangles:\n\n");
  printf("Enter the length of your triangle's side A: ");

  if (scanf("%lf", &a) != 1) /* scanf_s behaves similar in terms of the return value */
  {
    fputs("error msg",stderr);
    return -1;
  }
  getchar(); /* consuming the leftover newline */

  printf("The length of the triangle's side A is: %lf\n",a);

  printf("\nPress the <ENTER> key to exit.\n");

  while (getchar() != '\n') /* waiting for newline input */
    ;

  return 0;
}
```

Alternatively and far better, you could use `fgets()`to get the input as a string from the user and later use `sscanf()` to parse it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 500

int main(void)
{
  char buff[MAX_SIZE] = {0};
  double a = 0, b = 0, c = 0;
  double x = 0;

  printf("Lab 1B - Triangles:\n\n");
  printf("Enter the length of your triangle's side A: ");

  fgets(buff,MAX_SIZE,stdin);

  if (sscanf(buff,"%lf",&a) != 1)
  {
    fputs("error msg",stderr);
    return -1;
  }

  printf("The length of the triangle's side A is: %lf\n",a);

  printf("\nPress the <ENTER> key to exit.\n");

  while (getchar() != '\n')
    ;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The first solution doesn't handle the user typing extra characters after the number before pressing enter ; the second one doesn't handle input larger than MAX_SIZE , and both of them go into an infinite loop if the input is closed .   See linked duplicate question for some code that addresses all of these issues

Answer (score -1):

The issue is because `scanf` function only reads until non-space or non-newline character. After executing `scanf()`, `\n` from the first input is still in the buffer.
When you call `getchar()` again, it accepts the newline character and the program terminates.

One easy way to fix it is to call `getchar()` again right after `scanf` to consume the newline character.

Another way is to put space or newline character in scanf.
Reference: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/problem-with-scanf-when-there-is-fgetsgetsscanf-after-it/

```c
scanf_s("%lf ", &a);
// or
scanf_s("%lf\n", &a);
```

Comment: When I enter the blank space or the '\n' character into the format string of the scanf_s command, the user needs to enter TWO values (two double values followed with the <ENTER> key each) to get past the Side A input, and then the program AGAIN skips the getchar() command!

Comment: A trailing whitespace in the format string is an awful idea because it means to never stop reading until a non-whitespace character is entered