# I'm writing this program to find double digit odd numbers in a single number and I'm stuck

Tags: c

I'm writing this program to find double digit odd numbers in a single number and I'm stuck.

For ex- **In the number 56789 there are two double digit odd numbers: 67 & 89.** I've written the code for this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
    int num,rem=0;
    int odd=0;
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    while(num>0)
    {
        rem=(num%100);
        printf("%d\n",rem);
        if(rem%2!=0)
        {
            odd++;
        }
        num=num/10;
        
    }
    printf("Odd digits count is: %d",odd);
    return 0;
}
```

**Here's my problem:**

[image: Input: 56789, output: "89\n78\n67\n56\n5\nOdd digit count is: 3"]

**Expected Output:**
**67
89
Total number of odd digit numbers: 2**

Comment: Side note: [always check the return value of `scanf`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10084224/how-do-we-test-the-return-values-from-the-scanf-function).

Comment: Note that `conio.h` is not portable and completely unnecessary here. Why do you need it? I suggest removing that include.

Comment: We were always taught that stdio.h and conio.h go hand-in-hand. Thanks I'll remember it from now on.

Comment: Don't post text as images please

Comment: `conio.h` has never been a `C` standard include file; this will limit the computers on which your programme will compile. Unless you need it's system-dependant functionality, it's best if you don't include it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`while(num>0)` allows single and double digit numbers.
`while(num>=10)` allows only double digit numbers.