# How to stop an C "Command-Application" Programm with Enter

Tags: c

This is my code, my question is how can I stop "terminate" ... the code if the user presses enter on the first scanf?

I want to stop the Programm if the user presses enter, but I don't have an Idea how to do so..

````
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int zeichenkette;

    // abfragen wie lange unser zeichenkette sein soll
    printf("Wie viele Zahlen wollen sie eingeben: ", zeichenkette);
    scanf("%i", &zeichenkette);


    // hier wird die länge des arrays bestimmt
    int* array = malloc(zeichenkette * sizeof(int));


    // deklaration
    int sum = 0;
    int lowest = 32767;
    int max = 0;



    for(int i = 0; i < zeichenkette; i++) {

        // zahl angabe, diese wird zum array hinzugefügt
        printf("Geben sie eine Zahl an:  \n");
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);

        // Der summe wird immer mit der geraden array integer addiert
        sum = sum + array[i];

        // wenn eine zahl gröẞer als 0 ist dann max variable überschreiben
        if(max < array[i]) {
            max = array[i];
        };

        // wenn es eine zahl in der array kleiner als 32767 gibt dann überschreiben
        if(lowest > array[i]) {
            lowest = array[i];
        };

    };


    // da wir die summe schon haben und in die zeichenkette variable die länge haben können wir der mittelwert berechnen
    int mittelwert = sum/zeichenkette;

    // Ausgabe
    printf("Summe: %i \nMittelwert: %i\nMax: %i\nMin: %i\n", sum, mittelwert, max, lowest);

}```
````

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use `scanf()` for something like that, instead you could use `fgets()` and `sscanf()` or `strtol()` to later parse the string.

- `strtol()`

  ```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>

   #define MAX_LEN 500

   int main()
   {
       long int zeichenkette = 0L;
       char *endptr = NULL;
       char buff[MAX_LEN];

       // abfragen wie lange unser zeichenkette sein soll
       printf("Wie viele Zahlen wollen sie eingeben: ");

       if(fgets(buff,MAX_LEN,stdin) == NULL)
       {
           fprintf(stderr,"error handling here");
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }

       if (buff[0] == '\n') /* first char in buff is the newline char */
       {
           puts("Exiting");
           exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
       }
       else
       {
           zeichenkette = strtol(buff,&endptr,0); /* could do some error checking here, errno and enptr */
       }
   /* ... */
  ```
- `sscanf()`

  ```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>

   #define MAX_LEN 500

   int main()
   {
       int zeichenkette = 0;
       char *endptr = NULL;
       char buff[MAX_LEN];

       // abfragen wie lange unser zeichenkette sein soll
       printf("Wie viele Zahlen wollen sie eingeben: ");

       if(fgets(buff,MAX_LEN,stdin) == NULL)
       {
           fprintf(stderr,"error handling here");
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }

       if (buff[0] == '\n')
       {
           puts("Exiting");
           exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
       }
       else
       {
           if (sscanf(buff,"%d",&zeichenkette) != 1) /* always check the return value of scanf() */
           {
               fprintf(stderr,"error handling");
               exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
           }
       }
   /* ... */
  ```

As a side note, [you should always check the return value of `scanf()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10084224/how-do-we-test-the-return-values-from-the-scanf-function), thi way you can detect errors on input.