# Why does it tell me its an Armstrong number when I enter strings?

Tags: c, digits

[image]This is the code for finding an Armstrong number of 3 digits. But when i enter strings or any other special character it categorizes it as an armstrong number while it should be other way around.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  int a, original, rev, rem;
  printf("Enter the number : \n");
  scanf("%d", & a);

  original = a;

  rev = 0;
  while (a != 0) {

    rem = a % 10;
    rev = rev + (rem * rem * rem);
    a /= 10;
  }
  if (rev == original) {
    printf("Its an Armstrong number\n");
  } else {
    printf("Its not an Armstrong number \n");
  }

}
```

Comment: For me it works: `Enter the number : 
aaaa
Its not an Armstrong number`

Comment: `scanf` is expecting an integer so I guess it will cause undefined behaivour if the input is a string.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: [**Always** check the return values of `scanf()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10084224/995714)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check the result of `scanf` - it will return the number of items successfully converted and assigned.

```
if ( scanf( "%d", &a ) != 1 )
  // bad input
else
  // check if a is an armstrong #
```

An input like `nnnniii` is not a valid integer, so the read fails and `a` *is not updated*.

While the initial value of `auto` variables is *indeterminate*, it's possible that `a` has an initial value of `0`, so your test passes by accident.

Answer (score 3):

It is Undefined Behaviour as you use not initialized variable `a`.

You should have checked for the incorrect input:

```
  if(scanf("%d", &a) != 1)
  {
    printf("Invalid input\n");
    return 1;
  }
```

Comment: Yes, need to check the input value is number or not.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  int a, original, rev, rem;
  printf("Enter the number : \n");
  if(scanf("%d", &a) != 1)
  {
    printf("This is not number\n");
    return 1;
  }
 
  original = a;
  rev = 0;
  while (a != 0) {
    rem = a % 10;
    rev = rev + (rem * rem * rem);
    a /= 10;
  }

 if (rev == original) {
    printf("Its an Armstrong number\n");
  } else {
    printf("Its not an Armstrong number \n");
  }

}
```

When you get value, you need to check it is number or not.